# In Blender how can I open a .blend file and revert the UI layout to default settings?

Tags: layout, blender

I have a .blend project started with Blender 2.49b and now I'm using Blender 2.5: I like Blender 2.5 default layout the most, but how can I use it without have to restart the whole project from scratch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there is a direct way to convert the files so that the window layout converts to the new 2.5 layout, however this solution should accomplish what you want.

If you just start Blender with a new scene, then import the scene from your old file it should work.

1. Start Blender 2.5
2. Delete the default box, camera and light (It won't let you delete World yet), Just press **a** until everything is selected in the 3D view and then **x** to delete.
3. Press **Shift + F1** to import from library file.
4. In the file dialog, find your old *.blend* file and click on it then click into the *scene* folder inside of it and select your scene. Then click on the **Link/Append from Library** button.
5. Now your old scene is loaded into the current working session. Just click on the **X** button next to the current scene to delete the current scene and you should see your old scene.  You might want to rename this scene to just be *Scene*.  You also may want to rename what is now called *World.001* in your old scene to just *World*.  This happened when you loaded your scene and there were two things called *World*

Answer (score 4):

There is an easy way for this:

Start a new file in Blender 2.5, so the default layout is active. Press Ctrl-O to bring the open dialog in front. Now deactive the checkbox "Load UI" in the left panel under "Open Blender File" and load the old file as usual. It will be loaded without any embedded UI layouts.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using a later version, say Blender 2.83.3, it has changed. Press <kbd>Ctrl+O</kbd> to bring up the dialog, then open the Settings file, the gearwheel in the upper right corner, and there you will find the "Load UI (or not)" checkbox. It may also work for Blender 2.9 as well.